# HTTP Status 404 error while loading controller URL in the IIS5.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my asp.net MVC application, the Home controller works without any problems. But remaining controller class or action method couldn't call instead of i got the HTTP status 404 error - File not found.
MY web-server - IIS 5.1

**Note**: I added wild character in the configuration (.*)
 the following code snippet contains Global.asx file

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: do you have a route maps other than the default and if yes in what order, can add a url that you are trying to access and it gives you 404

Comment: it have only default route map..what should i do for this? if u know plz suggested me.

Comment: can you add as url that you are unable to access,

Comment: Got work.....plz refer this url  http://www.dotnetacademy.blogspot.in/2012/01/setup-aspnet-mvc3-on-iis-5.html  . I missed 7th point